# ( Chronicles 26:20-28) Differences/Similarities between treasures of the dedicated gifts and the treasures of the house of God

Tags: hebrew-bible, money

In order to get a better understanding of how finances/money that the ancient Israelites gave to government and/or religious institutes, I was trying to get a better understanding of what made up the ancient Israelite's treasury(regardless of whether it's their government or religious temple or a combination of both)

In the following verses,

1) Does the **the treasures of the house of God** include
-regular tithing
-regular taxation of the Israelite people?

2) Does the **treasures of the dedicated gifts** include
-finances/money/material goods given above and beyond the expected requirement or legal requirement?

3) Could someone please elaborate on the differences/similarities between **treasures of the dedicated gifts** and  **the treasures of the house of God**?

> 1 Chronicles 26:20-28 New American Standard Bible (NASB) Keepers of
>   the Treasure
>
> 20 [a]The Levites, their relatives, [b]had charge of **the treasures of
>   the house of God** and of the **treasures of the dedicated gifts**. 21 The
>   sons of Ladan, the sons of the Gershonites belonging to Ladan, namely,
>   the Jehielites, were the heads of the fathers’ households, belonging
>   to Ladan the Gershonite.
>
> 22 The sons of Jehieli, Zetham and Joel his brother, [c]had charge of
>   the **treasures of the house of the Lord**. 23 As for the Amramites, the
>   Izharites, the Hebronites and the Uzzielites, 24 Shebuel the son of
>   Gershom, the son of Moses, was officer over the treasures. 25 His
>   relatives by Eliezer were Rehabiah his son, Jeshaiah his son, Joram
>   his son, Zichri his son and Shelomoth his son. 26 This Shelomoth and
>   his relatives [d]had charge of **all the treasures of the dedicated
>   gifts** which King David and the heads of the fathers’ households, the
>   commanders of thousands and hundreds, and the commanders of the army,
>   had dedicated. 27 They dedicated [e]part of the spoil won in battles
>   to repair the house of the Lord. 28 And all that Samuel the seer had
>   dedicated and Saul the son of Kish, Abner the son of Ner and Joab the
>   son of Zeruiah, everyone who had dedicated anything, all of this was
>   [f]in the care of [g]Shelomoth and his relatives.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that David instituted the treasury of the temple(1Ch 28:11-13) to tell the Levites that they could take out of it what was already theirs to begin with, similarly to how God did not allow firstborn animals to be 'sanctified' to him(Lev 27:26), not because it wasn't holy, but because it was already his to begin with. Therefore the treasury of David likely would not have included such things as the tithe, among other things(e.g. first of the ...), which belonged to the priesthood, yet were nonetheless present in the temple(Tobiah's chamber for example, also 2Ch 31:11-12).

As far as the dedicated things, I take this as things dedicated to the building or upkeep of the temple versus things built by David, or belonging to David/Solomon(e.g. shields - 2Ki 11:10, jewels - 1Ch 29:8).